# How linux installation process works

Tags: linux

can anyone explain me how Linux installation process works?

With Windows, installation process starts with Windows Setup. It's a program that installs Windows. Setup starts and restarts a computer, collects informations, copies files, and applies settings.

What is for Linux like Setup for Windows, and are there any major differences between installation process of Linux and Windows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The devil is always in the details (which also differ between Linux distributions) but at a high level the process is similar: boot from installation medium - scan hardware - (interact with user of follow automated deployment)  - prepare installation target - copy files - install boot loader - reboot (and eject installation medium) - run newly installed operating system

Comment: _Linux_ is usually installed by something like `aptitude install linux-image...`. What you probably meant to ask is how the Debian/Ubuntu/CentOS/Gentoo/Android/ChromeOS (that is a Linux-based operating system) installation process works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux installation is very similar to the Windows one, except for a few things:

- Linux installation starts by booting from an external device (CD/DVD, USB Drive, ...), when Windows installation usually starts by booting a CD, or from the hard drive of a new PC.
- The Linux installation also has a step of collecting information, and copying files. A big difference is that the user has a little more control on the way to install the system on Linux than on Windows. For example, experiences users can choose how organize the disk partitions (Swap, /home, etc...).
- Also a big difference is that Linux installation usually allows to choose which software you want to install. The choice can often be done by groups, or individually.
- The post installation step provides the way to choose the root password, and eventually create new users.

I think that in general, the Linux installation allows more options and control than the Windows one.

Answer (score 3):

Xavier posted a good summary of the overall process, for a Red Hat (Fedora/CentOS) distribution.  With Ubuntu (and flavours), you tend not to get options regarding which software packages to install (you can install those later).

Additionally, there is no root account setup.  Ubuntu uses sudo by default and leaves the root password unset.  So the difference between Red Hat and Ubuntu in this instance is that Ubuntu has you set up a user account that will have sudo access which allows you to do root things, or fully activate the root account if you choose.

I haven't used any other distributions in any depth, so I cannot comment on how their installation process may differ.